# Errors in parsing a webpage using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to parse a webpage using jQuery. This is my code:

```
$.get(u, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);

        $(data).find('meta').each(function()
        {
            console.log($(this).text());
            //alert($(this).text());
            alert($(this).attr('content'));
            console.log($(this).attr('content'));
        });
    });
```

The page source is [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6645369).

There are many meta tags in this page but its only able to parse 6 of them namely :

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Affect and Engagement in Game-BasedLearning Environments" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The link between affect and student learning has been the subject of increasing attention in recent years. Affective states such as flow and curiosity tend to have positive correlations with learning while negative states such as boredom and frustrat..."/>   
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6645369" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/assets/img/logo-ieee-200x200.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IEEE Xplore" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="179657148834307" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i got the `302` error while running your script

Comment: This isn't the full code initialize the variable u by the url..

Comment: Have you tried to get the number of meta tags?

Comment: I try this code and I get all the meta tag:
`var x = [];
jQuery('meta').each(function({
   x.push(jQuery(this));
});
console.debug(x);`

Comment: By this code I am also able to do it ..any idea why my code isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will skip all meta-Tags which do not have closing brackets.

You therefore would be forced to parse the response using a regular expression, but this is in fact ugly.

It's very sad, that we still live in a world where there is such HTML out there.

If you really want to go that path, you could do some thing like this

```
data = data.replace(/(<meta.*[^\/])>/g, "$1/>");
```

before doing the "find" on it.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. HTML5 does not require self-closing tags for elements which do not require inner HTML? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg2er/)

Comment: Updated it to match the given example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kg2er/1/ Maybe it is a jQuery bug which only applies to the "head" section.

Comment: I think there is somr problem with your regex expression as it close the meta tags but removes last " of tags

Comment: I moved the closing round bracket back a bit some minutes ago... :)

Comment: I am still not able to get all the meta tags, now the tags are even closed..Does it have something to do with the fact that they aren't inside body ?but my data shows all the meta tags.

Comment: hm. cross origin policy doesn't allow to run the snippet in jsfiddle... :(

Answer (score 0):

You must append the response to an element and then get the meta.

```
$(data).appendTo("#test"); 
var m = $('#test').find('meta');
alert(m.length);
$('#test').html(''); // delete content
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B4ATz/